# Question about notation $P(X_1 = i | X_1 + X_2 = n)$

Tags: statistics

This is a homework question and I'm having a hard time finding out what the notation of the conditional means.

The random variables have identical geometric distrubution, I need to prove the following.
$i = 1,2,...,n-1$
$P(X_1 = i | X_1 + X_2 = n) = \frac{1}{n - 1}$

An example of my thoughts $i = 1, n = 2$ only one combination of $X_1 =1, X_2 = 1$, therefor the probability of $P(X_1= 1)$ must occured

With $i = 2, n = 3$ there are two combination $\{(X_1 =1, X_2 = 2), (X_1 =2, X_2 = 1)\}$, therefor the probability of $P(X_1 = 2 | X_1 + X_2 = n) = 1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking that if two random variables $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d geometrically and you know their sum, what is the conditional distribution of the value of the first variable? We proceed as:

Suppose $X_i\sim~\text{Geom}(p)$. Then:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2=n)=\sum_{1\le k \le n-1}\mathbb{P}(X_1=k)\mathbb{P}(X_2=n-k)=\sum_{1\le k \le n-1}(p(1-p)^k)(p(1-p)^{n-k})=\sum_{1\le k \le n-1}p^2(1-p)^n=(n-1)p^2(1-p)^n$$

Then, employing Bayes' rule:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=i\vert X_1+X_2=n)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1=i\cap X_1+X_2=n)}{\mathbb{P}( X_1+X_2=n)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1=i\cap X_2=n-i)}{\mathbb{P}( X_1+X_2=n)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1=i)\mathbb{P}(X_2=n-i)}{\mathbb{P}( X_1+X_2=n)}=\frac{(p(1-p)^k)(p(1-p)^{n-k})}{(n-1)p^2(1-p)^n}=\frac{1}{n-1}$$

As an aside, one can think of the question as being: Say we have two (possibly biased) coins, and we flip the first coin until we see "heads" for the first time, and then we flip the second coin until we see "heads" on it for the first time. Provided this whole process takes us $n$ flips, how long did it take us to see the first heads? The answer tells us that we are, in fact, equally likely to see it in any of the first $(n-1)$ flips.